# Can producer have multiple Kafka topics?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have multiple producers writing to single topic which is default as defined in policy, is it possible to create new topic without changing the default topic ? In other words, one producer same logs to multiple topics possible ?

Comment: can you please elaborate what you are trying to say ?

Comment: Do you want to create a topic?

Comment: One producer to multiple topics ?

Answer (score 3):

> In other words, one producer same logs to multiple topics possible ?

Yes, one producer can produce to multiple topics. The relation between the topic and a producer is *not* one-to-one.

**Example:**

```
 producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("my-topic", "key", "val"));
```

The `send()` method takes a `ProducerRecord` which contains the topic name. So we can give different topic names to each `send()` call.

However, the `key.serializer` and `value.serializer` matters. We specify only one `key.serializer` and one `value.serializer` per-producer rather than per-topic.
This being the case, all of your topic messages can be serialized using those serializers only.

If you want to support different objects, either write a custom serializer that is common for all of them (perhaps, a Json Serializer) or convert your objects to the format that your serializers can serialize (for ex, `String` for `StringSerializer`, `byte[]` for `ByteArraySerializer` etc)